# jQuery onClick works for first two clicks but stops after that

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to use jQuery to load a specific div from a separate page on my server into a div on the current page. The code is located in my header and it works successfully for the first two clicks on the website but not after that.

The code I'm using is:

```
 <script type="text/Javascript">
$('a').click(function(e) {
$("#container").load($(this).attr('href') + " #wrapper");
e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

I realize the site is not complete or fully functional, but it can be tried at: [dev.justapo.co](http://dev.justapo.co) right now by doing the below steps:

1. Click on one of the posts
2. Once the post loads, click the title in the header
3. Now click any link on the page - the jQuery is broken

Any help is much appreciated, am trying to learn jQuery and not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try -

```
$('html').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
   $("#container").load($(this).attr('href') + " #wrapper");
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

### update

i just look into your site. You may need to do something like this -

```
$('#primary a').click(function(){
   $("#container").load($(this).attr('href') + " #wrapper");
   return false;
});
```

You are facing problem because this id `primary` and and ID can't be duplicate. You should need to use class.

Comment: Nice! This worked for me perfectly. Now I wish I had just asked the question instead of hitting my head against the wall for so long! Thank you so so much! :)

Comment: Am curious what the difference is here that fixes the code? The 'html' allows any link on the page?

Comment: @Herp You are dynamically create your element, so you can't attach event handler directly to them, you must use delegation with [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method.

Comment: i used HTML just for example. You can use parent element of a tag

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you! The weird thing is the code seems to break the jQuery slider on the homepage when you navigate back, but that's another issue to solve I suppose! :)

Comment: You can try load jQuery slider again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that $('a').click() attaches the event handler to all anchor elements at the time the code is executed, and newly created ones will not have that handler set.

You'll want to use delegation, like so:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', handler_function);
```

See the docs for [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('html').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
$("#container").load($(this).attr('href') + " #wrapper");
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Tried this and it didn't appear to resolve the issue, sorry :(

Comment: I think that you want to use `on` method for delegation, but you missed something there `;)`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can also try this code

```
$('a').live("click",function(e) {
$("#container").load($(this).attr('href') + " #wrapper");
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Looking at your and HADI's answer, what difference does '.live' do? Both answers appear to be valid.

Comment: `live` is depreciated. From the jquery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/): As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.

Comment: That makes much more sense :)